# HIVE QL: split column into 2 columns and rank each column

Tags: hadoop, hive

### code

```
   select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6
   from table
   where c5 in ('a', 'b')
```

---

From here, I want to split column c5 into two columns and then rank those based on the value they have for c6. One column should be made up of all a results, and the other should be all b results. I have been able to rank them using rank() over, but have been unable to split the columns apart. I haven't gotten the techniques other people have used to work for me.

Comment: What kind of data is in column 5?  How ***specificly*** have you been unable to split the columns?  Examples.  Examples.  Examples.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 c6 has ints, c5 has strings. A or B will never be in the same cell together. A= "machine_play" and B="machine_results". Someone suggested split() but I am not sure how it would apply.

Comment: Example of data please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6, rank() over (partition by ... order by case when c5='a' then 1 case when c5='b' then 2 end) as rnk;
```

I do not understand completely what c5 contains exactly. Replace conditions like `when c5='a'` in case with yours.